# Bit operation in c++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I want to take bitwise XOR of a number with 4294967295 i.e.(pow(2,32)-1). Here I am using : number^4294967295 directly. But the result is wrong.So how does this operation takes place. Suggest if any better way to do this.

P.S- I am using this technique in https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-bits .

Edit1 : result of 1^4294967295 (00000000000000000000000000000001^11111111111111111111111111111111) should 
 be 4294967294 (11111111111111111111111111111110).

Edit2 : Code included :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {  
int t;
cin>>t;
int i=31;

while(t--){
    int  var;
    char arr[i];
    int temp = 4294967295;
    cin>>var;
    var= var^temp;
    cout<<var<<endl;

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the code, post your expectation, post the erroneous output.

Comment: Wouldn't `~number` be a more natural choice?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the result is wrong? What result do you get? What result did you expect? And what is the value of `number`?

Comment: **−1** You forgot to mention that "a number" is 32-bit integer. You forgot to mention what was "wrong". You forgot to provide your code. Please include such crucial information in later SO postings. Anyway, consider using the bit-flipping operator `~`.

Comment: Oh and on an unrelated note, when working with bits and bitwise operations, it's usually easier (and more readable) to use hexadecimal literals, in your case `0xffffffff`. Also, I suggest you turn on warnings when building, and read the warnings you get.

Comment: if number = 2147483647 then result = 2147483648.  if number = 0 result = 4294967295.

Comment: And lastly, what makes you think a *signed* integer would be `4294967294`? Again, I suggest you use hexadecimal values, and more importantly *print* the value in hexadecimal.

Comment: How many bits does your int have? Does your value for `temp` fit into an int? Maybe you want to use an `unsigned int`?

Comment: `int temp = 4294967295` is almost certainly undefined behavior, try using a `long long int` for `var` and `temp` instead.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sir I have included the code. And two results are there in my above comment. But when I run my code results are: -2147483648 for number=2147483647 and the result is -1 for number=0

Comment: Providing the code is better. :) Also should provide actual input, actual output, and what compiler you're using. It does matter. Maybe `int` with your compiler is 64-bit.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Earlier I was compiling my code on the online compiler provided by https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-bits so I don't know which compiler they use. But when I ran the same code on my computer (compiler: TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64Bit Release) the results are correct. kindly explain how the compiler affects the output. Thank you.

Comment: @KhagendraNathMahato: In Windows the size of `int` is 4 bytes, with 8-bit byte. That's 32 bits. Regardless of compiler, and yes, even in 64-bit Windows programming. You should best use the *unsigned* integer type from **`<stdint.h>`** that is guaranteed exactly 32-bits (if it is provided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an operator for that. Look at *bitwise not* in [this table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4eab163870f9f303))

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    uint32_t var;
    std::cin >> std::hex >> var;

    const uint32_t result = ~var;
    std::cout << std::hex << result << "\n";
}
```

Output (when given `1` as input):

```
fffffffe
```

---

If you insist on doing it your way, you need to use unsigned types. It'll also help to use a fixed-size type (such as [`uint32_t` from `<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)) and to represent your literals in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), for convenience ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdb868a7db8c663b)):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    const uint32_t mask = 0xffffffff;
    uint32_t var;
    std::cin >> std::hex >> var;

    const uint32_t result = var ^ mask;
    std::cout << std::hex << result << "\n";
}
```

Output (when given `1` as input):

```
fffffffe
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work correctly with following changes:

1. int  var;  --> change to --> unsigned int var;
2. int temp = 4294967295;  --> change to --> unsigned int temp = 4294967295;

signed int has range [−2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647]

unsigned int has range [0 to 4,294,967,295]